# How to find for each 3-input boolean function the minimum number of NAND operators needed to compute it

Tags: boolean-functions, circuits, minimization

I need to know for each of the $2^{2^3}$ boolean functions with $3$ inputs the
smallest boolean circuit made only of NAND gates computing it (smallest in terms
of the number gates).

I would be glad if someone could tell me a source where I can look this up
or a clever procedure to find the minimal circuits myself.

Answer (score 1):

For 3 inputs it's not $2^3$ functions but $2^{2^3}$ functions. Circuit minimization is generally hard. You could try using the aiger package http://fmv.jku.at/aiger/, which will give you a circuit but not necessarily minimal.